# Why is Express redirecting infinitely redirecting me?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to setup a multi language website with Express and NodeJs. My problem is I get redirected what it feels like 100 times and my browser is giving me a error that the webpage is not working because it redirected me too many times.

app.js

```
app.use('/', (req,res,next) => {
  res.redirect('/en-US');
  next();
});

app.use('/:lang', indexRouter);
app.use('/:lang/users', usersRouter);
```

index.js (indexRouter)

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: You are using a middleware to redirect to language page, remove the redirection from there and add it in router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index');
}) here

Comment: like that?
```router.use('/', (req,res,next) => {
  res.redirect('/en-US');
  next();
});```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? you are simply redirecting everything to /en-US including for /en-US,

Comment: I'm trying that every person that gets on my page like normal on /page1 gets redirected to /(language)/page1 e.g. /en-US/page1

Comment: Because `app.use('/', ...)` also matches `/en-US`. Move it to after everything else or change it to `app.get()` instead

Comment: It works, in the console is a 404 on /

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that this route handler:

```
app.use('/', (req,res,next) => {
  res.redirect('/en-US');
  next();
});
```

will get hit for not only `/`, but also `/en-US`.  `app.use()` matches any route handler for which the path is equal to or a subset of the requested path.  So, the browser requests "/", you redirect to "/en-US", which then redirects to "/en-US" and so on, an infinite loop.

I don't know the overall URL design of your site to know what the best overall solution is.  You can prevent the infinite redirect loop by just changing `app.use()` to `app.get()`:

```
app.get('/', (req,res,next) => {
  res.redirect('/en-US');
});
```

But, that will make the redirect only work for GET requests which may or may not be OK.  If you want all HTTP verbs to redirect, you could change to `app.all()`:

```
app.all('/', (req,res,next) => {
  res.redirect('/en-US');
});
```

The important thing to understand here is that `app.get()`, `app.post()`, `app.all()`, etc... all require an exact match for the URL path, whereas `app.use()` just requires a subset match.  This is a little understood aspect of the Express design.

---

In addition, remove the call to `next()` after you do `res.redirect()`.  At that point, you've sent the response, you don't want any other request handlers to see the request.  You're done with routing.

Comment: How can I fix that? I don't have that much knowledge about the different link types and expressions

Comment: @MauritzFunke - I've added a couple possible solutions.

Comment: Thank you very much, works like a charm but I still get a weird 404 error on "/" and I don't know why it appears. My browser debug console has no errors just the debug console of nodejs

Comment: @MauritzFunke - Yeah, another issue. After you call `res.redirect()`, remove the call to `next()`.  You've sent a response.  You're done with routing.  You don't want Express to try to keep routing the request as it will eventually hit its 404 handler.  I've edited my answer to include that.

Answer (score 0):

under your app.js

Try using

app.use('/', router )

Comment: Still does not work... I think it has something to do with the redirect to /en-US but I do not know what and why

Answer (score 0):

How about you try dealing with the '/' route through the app.js directly instead of  index.js

Comment: Why would that help? I think my code is way more cleaner than having that in one file

Comment: Try only the home route ( '/')...i once faced the same issue and that worked for me...all the other routes are okay as they are under the index.js