# Redirect through Middleware not working Node.js Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to use a middleware to redirect between `'/'` for english and `'/:lang'` routes to return the translated version of the html file when the detected language is not English.

With the redirect from the middleware I see that in the browser `'/it'` gets added but then neither of the two methods gets called so there's no redirect really.

So as test I moved the redirect directly in the `'/'` method and it works as expected.
Can you spot what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you very much.

## With the middleware

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  var language = req.acceptsLanguages('fr', 'es', 'en', 'it', 'de');
  console.log('browser language is: ', language);
  if (language !== 'en') {
    return res.redirect(`/${language}`);
  }


  next();
});


app.get('/:lang', (req, res) => {
  console.log('get /lang called');
  // const lang = req.lang; // undefined

  const lang = req.acceptsLanguages('fr', 'es', 'en', 'it', 'de'); 
  console.log('lang is: ', lang)
  res.sendFile(__dirname + `/index-${lang}.html`);
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
  console.log('get / called');
});
```

## Without the middleware

```
app.get('/:lang', (req, res, next) => {
  const lang = req.params.lang;
  console.log('get /lang called');
  console.log('lang is: ', lang);
  res.sendFile(__dirname + `/index-${lang}.html`);
});

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  const defaultLang = 'en'; // Default language is English
  const lang =
    req.acceptsLanguages('fr', 'es', 'en', 'it', 'de') || defaultLang;
  console.log('get / called');
  console.log('browser language is: ', lang);
  if (lang !== defaultLang) {
    return res.redirect(`/${lang}`);
  }
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure how it's handled in express but it looks like an infinite loop. You redirect and this redirect may be handled by the same middleware

Comment: this makes sense as no other route handler gets called and I get a bunch of prints from the middleware.. which I haven't noticed earlier.. guess is it time for a break lol..

Comment: First off, move the `app.get('/', ...)` route BEFORE the `app.get('/:lang', ...)` route as they may conflict.  You should also know that top level wildcard routes like `app.get('/:lang', ...)` can be problematic because they match ALL top level routes which prevents you from having `/about`, `/help`, `/robots.txt`, and so on unless you are extremely careful about your route ordering making sure that `app.get('/:lang', ...)` is ALWAYS specified LAST so the other top level routes always get a chance to match first.

Comment: ok, adding `if (req.path === `/${language}`) { return next(); }` before the redirect I avoid the loop, but then I cannot choose another language manually rather then the one from the browser..

Comment: @jfriend00 indeed! thanks for pointing it out, well needed reminder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to remove the `next()` from the middleware
as very well explained here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58956354/1851110)

Answer (score 1):

You need to get write this `const {lang} = req.params;` insted of this `// const lang = req.lang; // undefined` because you are not making requests to those route you are just accesing it using params so you are extracting the wrong thing here. Hope it helps >.<

Comment: Yes.. that's commented out.  I tried it but req.params.lang is always undefined.. that's why I get it from req.acceptsLanguages, at least you can check for a match

Comment: you should `console.log(req.params)` and see what it contains

Comment: @ion params are empty..it jut returns {}

Comment: it means that you don't receive them. Can you show us the URL you call?

Comment: i have tried your code with middleware, and i get this logs in the terminal ```
browser language is:  en
get /lang called
lang is:  it
browser language is:  en
get /lang called
lang is:  robots.txt
browser language is:  en
get /lang called
lang is:  favicon.ico
```
it seems you trigger infinite redirects

Comment: @ion yes, the problem was that next() was always called, resulting I a loop as the middleware was rewatching the redirect..hence the loop.

So I added an if statement to check if the path is neither  `'/'` or ``/${language}``and only then call  `next()`, in any other cate it will perform the redirect..
So on `/` it will check the browser language and redirect to the translated version eg. `/it`, but then if you manually change the url to `/en` it would still be redirected to `/it`.
So in `langFromPath` I take the language from path and serve the proper file. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @konrad and @ion, the problem was that next() was always called, resulting in a loop as the middleware was re-catching the redirect..hence the loop.

So I added an if statement to check if the path is neither  `'/'` or `/${language}`and only then call  `next()`, in any other case it will perform the redirect..

So on `/` it will check the browser language and redirect to the translated version eg. `/it`, but then if you manually change the url to `/en` it would still be redirected to `/it`.

Basically the first time it catches the request will redirect, and the second time (the redirect) will pass it through.

So far the solution would impede the manual setting of the language in the url say from `/it` to `/en` which I do want to enable.

So in `langFromPath` I take the language from path, check it against the supported, and serve the proper file wether is the auto-detected or the manually set one.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const lang = req.lang || 'en'; // Default language is English
  const { langParams } = req.params; // {}
  console.log('@ middleware req.path:', req.path); 

  const language = req.acceptsLanguages('fr', 'es', 'en', 'it', 'de') || lang;
  console.log('@ middleware browser language is: ', language);
  req.lang = language; // Store the chosen language in req.lang for later use

  // Check if the current request path already matches the desired language
  if (req.path != '/' || req.path === `/${language}`) {
    console.log('@middleware going forward directly\n\n');
    return next();
  }

  // Redirect to the appropriate translated version of index.html
  if (language !== 'en') {
    console.log('@middleware redirecting\n\n');
    return res.redirect(`/${language}`);
  }

  console.log('@middleware going forward\n\n');
  next(); // Proceed to the next middleware or route handler
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const { langParams } = req.params;
  console.log(langParams);

  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
  console.log('get / called');
  console.log('\n\n');
});

app.get('/:lang', (req, res) => {
  console.log('get /lang called');
  const { langParams } = req.params;
  console.log('langParams is: ', langParams); // undefined

  const langFromPath = req.path.substring(req.path.indexOf('/') + 1);
  console.log('langFromPath is:', langFromPath);
  const acceptedLanguages = ['fr', 'es', 'en', 'it', 'de'];

  const isAccepted = acceptedLanguages.includes(langFromPath);
  console.log(isAccepted);
  const lang =
    isAccepted == true
      ? langFromPath
      : req.acceptsLanguages('fr', 'es', 'en', 'it', 'de');

  console.log('lang is: ', lang);
  console.log('\n\n');
  res.sendFile(__dirname + `/index-${lang}.html`);
});
```